# Brownie Reverting Transactions With No Description Of Error

Tags: ganache, brownie

Getting error on add liquidity function with no description of the error.

Error:

```
CSAMM.addLiquidity  0:334  [476 / 29510689 gas]
│   
└── ERC201.transferFrom  [CALL]  123:322  [29510213 gas]
        ├── address: 0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512
        ├── value: 0
        ├── input arguments:
        │   ├── sender: 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266
        │   ├── recipient: 0x5FC8d32690cc91D4c39d9d3abcBD16989F875707
        │   └── amount: 50
        └── revert reason: 0x4e487b710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011
```

Using copied CSAMM code from:
https://solidity-by-example.org/defi/constant-sum-amm
ERC20:
https://solidity-by-example.org/app/erc20

Setting gas or else the CSAMM wont deploy right before hand

```
some_gas_price = 500000000
CSAMM.deploy('0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512','0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0', {'from': accounts[0], "gas_price": some_gas_price})
Transaction sent: 0xa69ee008cf0550bd78979a4c91bdf86fcab0d71f1b8bdb06d9d2071ee4e5ace9
  Gas price: 0.5 gwei   Gas limit: 30000000   Nonce: 12
  CSAMM.constructor confirmed   Block: 13   Gas used: 711227 (2.37%)
  CSAMM deployed at: 0xA51c1fc2f0D1a1b8494Ed1FE312d7C3a78Ed91C0

<CSAMM Contract '0xA51c1fc2f0D1a1b8494Ed1FE312d7C3a78Ed91C0'>
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt approve to spend my erc20s